# How to recover queries with Teradata?

Tags: teradata

I am submitting queries with `vb script` (NOT sql assistant). Now I accidentally deleted that vb script file . How can I recover the queries that I submitted ? Where are they stored in Teradata ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most TD systems enable the Database Query Log (DBQL), so there's a high probability that your SQL was captured. You might try if you got access to it:

```
SELECT * FROM dbc.QryLogV 
WHERE UserName = USER;
```

But even if this works you might still not find the required queries, as all data is regularly moved from the DBQL base tables to a history database (probably every day). So you better contact your DBA and ask for assistance :-)

If QueryText in dbc.QryLogV is empty (or just partial text) you can check QryLogSQLV (hopefully it's populated):

```
SELECT * FROM dbc.QRryLogSQLV
WHERE QueryId IN 
 ( 
   SELECT QueryId FROM dbc.QryLogV 
    WHERE UserName = USER
    AND some more conditions to find the correct queries
 )
```

Comment: +1 thank you. but `QryLogV ` table does not have any `txt` columns , it only has some dates, error codes . . . but no text column to hold queries

Comment: There's a column QueryText, but this could be empty, in that case you might find it in dbc.QryLogSQLV, I edit my answer

Comment: Thank You! These tables contain ALL sqls that I ran via `SQLassistant`, but queries that were run using `vb script` are not there for some reason

Comment: Bad luck, you still should contact your DBA